# PHP,mysql,ecommerce website development

Tags: php, jquery, oop

M new to ecommerce website development. I just want to get the idea about how to start making ecommerce website with custom php using oop. Can anyone guide me about what are the security featues i have to add? Thanx in advance :-)

Comment: Making an ecommerce engine from scratch really isn't for a newbie...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best place to start would be to follow one of the [many](http://www.booktopia.com.au/beginning-php-5-and-mysql-e-commerce-christian-darie/prod9781590593929.html?source=pla&gclid=CJ2QpOqJ1b0CFYHhpAodn0MAxw) [books](http://www.larryullman.com/books/effortless-e-commerce-with-php-and-mysql/) out there which teach OOP PHP and related technologies/languages whist building an ecommerce system from scratch.

These books usually go through all aspects of the system including security etc and will give you a good starting point and understanding of the ecommerce system you create. There will most likely be some aspects that are not covered in detail but the books will usually give a good outline or point you in the direction to find out more information.

From there research online or through further reading the latest techniques related to security etc that you can then implement into your system.

I must admit, as ceejayoz suggested this is not really a newbie thing to start off with, especially if you intend to make it a full production system (release to the public)

I used similar books when I was first starting out with PHP but used them only to gain an understanding of OOP techniques, PHP syntax and best practices.

The one I followed was for a CMS System, I did not use this system outside my own development environment, only to learn and understand. From there I began using an off the shelf product, but had the skills and understanding to modify the system as I desired.

ecommerce systems can be incredibly complex, especially if you are a newbie to PHP or even programming. If you are looking at an ecommerce site for your business then use an off the shelf product. If you are a developer looking to branch out onto the web and would like to sell off your own ecommerce system then it would still probably be a whole lot better to grab and customise an existing open source system (no need to re invent the wheel)

Comment: hi everyone, thaxn for your suggestions :-) so, which open source is best for e-commerce websites?

Comment: Hi Varun, It really depends on your situation and what you want. For a standalone ecommerce system [try one of these](http://www.webappers.com/2010/07/09/15-best-free-open-source-ecommerce-platforms/). Personally I have used Majento, osCommerce and PrestaShop for various projects and have liked working with each one for different reasons, each have their pros/cons so it is worth researching the features and picking the best fit. Majento has a paid and open source version, the others are open source.

Comment: hi Jake thank you so much for your suggestion :-) can you guide me from where i can get the tutorials for magento etc. I have the knowledge of classes in php. I have done small projects using oop. That's y i was thinking for custom code for ecommerce. But i want to learn these open source frameworks also :-)

Comment: Hi Varun, Depending on what level of detail you would like to learn.. [here](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/) are some basic tutorials, geared more towards setup and usage. [Magento themselves](http://magento.com/training/overview) offer training and certifications which I imagine would go into more details and probably go into coding/APIs etc. Otherwise Google is your friend, there are heaps of sites out there with tutorials and training for magento.

Comment: hey!!! Jake thank you so much for giving me your precious time and suggestions :-) I will go through these tutorials.

Comment: Not a problem. If you are happy with my answer feel free to click the green tick so that everyone knows your question has been answered ;)

Comment: sorry for this ... but m new to stack overflow and don't know where is that green tick? :-P

Comment: No Worries. To the left of my original answer there are up/down arrows, then under that is a tick (its actually white sorry) click that and it will go green :) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't do this.** If you're asking questions about "security features", you are not in a position to build a secure e-commerce site.

It's much better to take an [off the shelf site](http://www.webappers.com/2010/07/09/15-best-free-open-source-ecommerce-platforms/) and customize it to suit your needs. 90-95% of the functionality will be already implemented, so you can focus on making the 5-10% that really differentiates your site as best as it can be.

Once you've worked with several e-commerce packages and are familiar with their source code and database structures, you *might* be ready to build your own.

Comment: hi tadman, thaxn for your suggestion :-) so, which open source is best for e-commerce websites?

Comment: Have a look at that link and make an assessment based on your needs. Some are very feature packed but more complicated to use, others simpler and maybe adequate for what you need. It's really hard to say.